# AS3 Tint Bitmap

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air

I have a spritesheet for a project I am working on and I need to be able to change the tint of the image so I can se space. The image has some simple texture on it but it will be displayed in 5 different colors. I attached an image to see exactly what I am talking about: http://i42.tinypic.com/29443l5.png

I tried to achieve my desired effect using this on the resulting sprite:

```
var c:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
c.color = 0xf30909;
transform.colorTransform = c;
```

But I get everything red, not as I want. I am building for AIR so the package fl.motion.Color can't be imported (or at least Flash Builder 4.5 does not have it). Any idea on how I can achieve the desired effect? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `color` property sets the *offset*, i.e. it makes the `ColorTransform` add the color value to your image. You probably want to use the `Multiplier` properties. See [ColorTransform documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html#blueMultiplier).

Comment: Yes! That is what I need. Now I only have to see the exact values needed...but that is another story. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Just for the sake of completeness...

```
public function Tint(display:DisplayObject, color:uint) {
    display.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(color >> 16 & 0x0000FF / 255, color >> 8 & 0x0000FF / 255, color & 0x0000FF / 255);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping to get started with a ***working example***!

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I came here for.